# Extracting specific text from HTML texts

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all

I am not so familiar with regex. I am trying to obtain the results described at the bottom. Here is what I have done so far (note that `$page` contains tabulators):

```
$page = "<div class=\"title-container\">
                            <h1>Text here<span> /Sub-text/</span> </h1>
                                                     </div>";
// TITLE
preg_match_all ('/<h1>(.*)<\/h1>/U', $page, $out);
$hutitle = preg_replace("#<span>(.*)<\/span>\s#", "", $out[1][0]);

$entitle = preg_replace("'(.*)<span> /'", "", $out[1][0]);
```

I would like to get this:

```
$hutitle = "Text here"; 
$entitle = "Sub-text"; (Without html and "/")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using DOM with `trim`, no need for regex, here is a working code for your concrete case:

```
$page = "<div class=\"title-container\">\n                            <h1>Text here<span> /Sub-text/</span> </h1>\n                                                     </div>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($page);
$hs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1');
foreach ($hs as $h) {
    $enttitlenodes = $h->getElementsByTagName('span');
    if ($enttitlenodes->length > 0 && $enttitlenodes->item(0)->tagName == 'span')
    {
        $entitle = trim($enttitlenodes->item(0)->nodeValue, " /");
        echo $entitle . "\n";
        $h->removeChild($enttitlenodes->item(0)); 
    }
    $hutitle = $h->nodeValue;
    echo $hutitle;
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/MLXPWo)

Comment: `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName` returns a `DOMNodeList` not an array, so you can't write `$h->getElementsByTagName('span')[0]` before php 5.6.3 but `$h->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)`. This doesn't means that it returns an array since php 5.6.3, but only that you can access items via array notation.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I see, I updated the code, it now even checks for `<span>` tag presence.

Comment: In this case instead of using count (that is designed to count array items), use the property `DOMNodeList::length`

Comment: Could you write this in not object oriented method?
And what is the min php version 5.?

Comment: @Gable: Do you mean you still insist a regex solution?

Comment: Well, I have never used the DOM method to extract html source code from url

Comment: @Gable: In this case, you do not extract HTML source, but the text contents, and I think DOM way is preferable and safer when you know your exact requirements. Certainly I can provide you a regex, but there are too many people here that will shout at me and you for using a "hammer instead of a screwdriver to fasten a screw". And this is just what I got for a light comment. :(

Comment: @Gable:I did not account for the DIV tag in my solution, but I do not see it in your regex attempt. Do you want to check for this tag presence? If yes, and there can be multiple H1 tags inside that DIV DOM solution will be the cleanest. If you do not need to account for the tag or there can be only one H1 tag per DIV, a regex solution is possible, too.

Comment: @stribizhev Than could you give me a reference guide for noobs? :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<h1>(.*?)<span> /(.*?)/</span>
```

$1 and $2 are the results as you expected.

Comment: `/<h1>(.*)<span>(.*?)<\/span>(.*)<\/h1>/`
This worked me

Comment: yes both are same in turn. safe way use it like that

Comment: try this in your notepad++ <h1>(.*?)<span> /(.*?)/</span></h1>

Comment: i think no need of \/

Comment: `// Get title 
    preg_match_all("/<h1>(.*)<span>(.*?)<\/span>(.*)<\/h1>/", $page, $matches);
 $ret["title"] = $matches[1][0];

    // Get original title
    preg_match_all("/<h1>(.*)<span>(.*?)<\/span>(.*)<\/h1>/", $page, $matches);
    if ($matches[1][0])
  //SUBSTR REMOVES " " than "/" and the last "/" this is the best solution because the title may have "/" in it.
        $ret["origtitle"] = substr($matches[2][0], 2, -1);`

This works well, thanks for your help